# How do you connect to one of the 5 wires of a low voltage cable in the middle of the run (the cable goes farther than the connection point)

Tags: wiring, low-voltage

In the below picture, A is a irrigation controller. BCD are inline valves with D being the main valve installed on the water tap and B and C being the manifold valves.

I have a 5 wire cable that runs all the way to the manifold and I am using just 3 of the 5 wires available.

Is there a standard/by code/recommended way to connect to the blue pair in the picture below ? I guess ideal I should open the cable the least I could (the obvious solution could be to open the cable and to tie into the green and the blue cable and then seal it back -with tape?- but I think there could be better options for this)

[image]

Comment: Low voltage(less than 50 volts) usually means you can do what you want without worrying about code.   If that section is in/near wet conditions, tape is usually not enough protection against moisture.  You want to keep it dry to prevent problems like corrosion.

Comment: Well then the question is mostly about an esthetical way to do it :-)

Comment: Is it in a wet or dry(in house or shed) place?  In a dry place just be neat, in wet there quite a few connectors/housings to keep it dry.

Comment: no it will be above the ground, on the wall below the irrigation line tap https://i.imgur.com/6tQ0h86.png  Here is the valve https://www.homedepot.ca/product/orbit-1-auto-inline-valve/1001644404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "standard way" is to bring the whole cable to and from point D.  If the cable is to be run, you run from A to D, and from D to B & C.

If the cable is already in place (and has no slack, and no "moves adds and changes" loop at either end) you cut it and add a point E that is just a junction so you can add enough more cable to go out to point D and back from point D.

Use waterproof wirenuts (standard in irrigation controls.)

Comment: the cable is lose and it is in the Proof of concept mode right now. If by "Bring" you mean a connection should be there then we are on the same page but that is what I am asking -what is a recommended way to interrupt the cable there to connect the main valve

Comment: Provide a junction box at point D if the device there does not have one. Cut enough cable to reach into that box from point A, and enough cable to reach from that box to points B&C. Join the appropriate wires from the two cables in the junction box, and join the wires to the device at point D as well. The green will be a three-wire join, the others will be two-wire joins.

Comment: I guess using one of these will do https://www.amazon.ca/Waterproof-Junction-electric-electrical-Connector/dp/B08LV9SLXJ